# Unity container factory with dependency on outside data

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, serilog, commandlineutils

I am writing a C# .NET Core 5.0 console application. This application uses CommandLineUtils to process command line arguments, Unity Container for DI, and Serilog for logging.

I am registering Serilog in my composition root:

```cs
public static void Setup(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterFactory<ILogger>(_ => new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateLogger(),
        new SingletonLifetimeManager());
}
```

However, I have a command line argument, `--debug`, that should reveal DEBUG level logs. If this option is not specified, it should keep the default INFO level. From the Serilog examples, the way they set DEBUG level is by adding calls to `LoggerConfiguration` object (i.e. `MinimumLevel.Debug()`)

But I don't know if I need to call this until after CLI processing takes place, which happens *after* I define the composition root.

Seems like I'm in a catch 22 situation. I know it's bad practice to `RegisterType()` outside of the root of the application. How should I solve this circular dependency?

**EDIT**

Here is my `Program` class which shows the order of things:

```cs
internal static class Program
{
    private static IUnityContainer Container { get; } = new UnityContainer();

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CompositionRoot.Setup(Container);

        var app = new CommandLineApplication<TrashCommand>();
        app.Conventions
            .UseDefaultConventions()
            .UseConstructorInjection(new UnityServiceProvider(Container));

        app.Execute(args);

        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I misinterpreted your question, but doesn't a construct such as the following answer your question?

```cs
public static void Setup(IUnityContainer container, bool logDebug)
{
    LogEventLevel level = logDebug ? LogEventLevel.Debug : LogEventLevel.Info.

    container.RegisterFactory<ILogger>(_ => new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .MinimumLevel.Is(level)
        .CreateLogger(),
        new SingletonLifetimeManager());
}
```

Or, alternatively:

```cs
public static void Setup(IUnityContainer container, bool logDebug)
{
    LogEventLevel level = logDebug ? LogEventLevel.Debug : LogEventLevel.Info.

    container.RegisterFactory<ILogger>(_ =>
        {
            var config = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Console();

            if (logDebug) config = config.MinimumLevel.Is(level);
            
            return config.CreateLogger();
        },
        new SingletonLifetimeManager());
}
```

Comment: The part you're missing is where `logDebug` comes from. Where does the caller get it? First step in my app is to set up the DI container. Then I parse command line arguments. The CLI argument `--debug` controls whether or not `logDebug` param is true or false. My CLI parser has a dependency on several services, so it needs the DI container to be set up before it is invoked.

Comment: I amended my question with an example that hopefully makes things more clear.

Comment: @void.pointer ahh... I see what you mean. CommandLineUtils parses the arguments only later, after you already configured the container. This seems a question/problem specific to CommandLineUtils. I'm unsure whether natemcmaster watches SO for questions about CommandLineUtils, but otherwise it would  be good to ask on [on GitHub](https://github.com/natemcmaster/CommandLineUtils/issues). btw, I'm interested in learning the answer. Please ping me if you have an answer to your question.

Comment: @void.pointer can't you inspect `args` for the desired argument and then call the provided solution above?

Comment: @Nkosi, although possible, it defeats the whole purpose of CLU, which contains complex logic of command-line argument parsing.

Comment: I am not sure that this is a CommandLineUtils problem. Why should it be concerned about how I construct my Serilog Logger object? Or about what specific command line options I define for my program? Am I missing your point?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the function of CLU, but isn't its function to parse the textual command line arguments into typed values for the application to use? So as I see it, the problem is that you require a parsed value before CLU parsed that value.

Comment: It's not that I require it, after all I could do as you say and just peek the raw args before they are parsed. It's about consistency and solving what seems to be a bigger underlying design problem in my application.

Comment: I fail to see this design issue in your application. The only thing I see is it is caused by way the CLU tool is used (or perhaps abused?). I'd really urge you to post a question with CLU to see whether you are using it incorrectly or if the maintainers have a solution for you.

Comment: The design philosophy here is about how to solve circular dependencies. This is just one example of many I've faced. I don't like having to short-cut, hack, or duplicate code to work around these issues. There's got to be a better solution. That's the reason for my question, hopefully I find a better answer.

Comment: Let me put it differently: most --if not all-- configuration values that are either read from the config or the command line are usually required during container configuration. They are required because those values need to 'flow' into registered application components. That makes the design of CLU rather odd, as it seems to parse the application's configuration *after* the container has been configured.